# SQL Server 2005 v 2008 for a medium volume classic asp site

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm running a classic asp app that's migrating to a .NET 4.0 app; it mostly does CRUD and some reporting (currently not via Reporting Services). I don't do many other kinds of remote jobs - the most I do is a simple replication of one table to another on the same server.

Is it worth going to 2008 given this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

1. Auditing comes with 2008 out of the box.
2. SQL 2008 provides the ability to limit the resources of queries.
3. Add CPU's on the fly.
4. Intellisense. Mentioned already.
5. Ability to compress data and use less disk space.
6. Declare and set a variables inline.

Answer (score 0):

Whether it is worth the upgrade dependes on what you value.

I would move to 2008 just to get the new features, bug fixes, and tools.

Answer (score 0):

2008 is easier to develop in (intellisense).  It also makes it easier to use things like Reporting Services, Analysis Services, and Integration Services.

2005 is totally fine for the scenario you've got, it's still a premium quality server.

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting fresh and have options - you might also want to consider:

[End of Mainstream Support for SQL Server 2005 and End of Service Pack Support for SQL Server 2008 SP1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2011/01/27/end-of-mainstream-support-for-sql-server-2005-and-end-of-service-pack-support-for-sql-server-2008-sp1.aspx)

SQL Server 2005 is officially "end of support" as of April 2011. Personally, I wouldn't pick that version anymore, over 2008 or 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm in the minority on this one. IMO, given what little you have told us, *the* reason for going up to 2008 would be a smooth upgrade path.

If you do not need data compression ( only in the Enterprise version BTW ), or do not need intellisense since you are using something else ( e.g. Visual Studio ) to build your queries or do not need adding CPUs on the fly ( because a quick reboot is acceptable ) then SQL 2008 probably will not provide enough benefit to justify the additional cost (again depending on your licensing situation). At some point, 2005 will become "ancient" technology (probably Nov 2011 when SQL Server 2011 comes out) and *that* might make things difficult from a feature set/support standpoint for developers. If you can wait until November until Denali is *supposed* to be released, then I would do that.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2005

- is 6 years old
- there are 2 later versions
- it's going out of support

Go with SQL Server 2008 of course.